# Neo4j Cypher query to show entire graph, including relationship properties?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm building a Neo4J system just do to visualization in the Neo4J browser.  I build the various nodes and relationships and I can visualize the database by running `match (n) return n`.  The problem is that the resulting display shows the relationship *names* but not their associated *properties*.  Can anyone tell me the cypher query to show the entire database including relationship properties?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The neo4j browser does not support visualizing *all* properties (for nodes or relationships) at the same time. Such a capability would generally result in a very congested and unusable visualization, especially since the browser would also have to display the property names.

You can, however, opt to show the value of a *single* property per node label or or relationship type as its caption. You can do that [manually](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/#_styling_neo4j_browser_visualization), or you can [edit the GRASS file](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/#_advanced_styling) to set all of the captions at once. As an example of how to set relationship captions in the GRASS file, the following entry in that file would specify that all `BAR` relationships should show their `foo` property:

```
relationship.BAR {
  caption: '{foo}';
}
```